# Windows Phone Application Project Type Unavailable in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I recently had to reinstall the OS on my dev box and I am now in the process of reinstalling various applications. I had previously installed the WP7 SDK without any problems but unfortunately I'm having problems this time around. The only project type I have available in the Silverlight for Windows Phone category is one that I downloaded from the online templates section.

[image: Missing Projects]

When I try to open it or any of the WP7 projects I created previously I get a "The project type is not supported by this installation." error. I am not sure what I am missing. I have followed the three steps listed [here](http://create.msdn.com/en-us/home/getting_started) so I've installed the SDK, the Dev Tools and the Dev Tools fix. The installation of VS2010 itself seems to be fine as I can create ASP.NET and Silverlight applications and run them without any problems.

Has anyone encountered something like this before?

**Edit:** I have installed Service Pack 1 for VS 2010 but that hasn't helped unfortunately.

**Edit:** I have also re-installed the Windows Phone Dev Tools and that installation reported no errors but I still get no projects under the Silverlight for Windows Phone category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have thankfully resolved this. Last night I uninstalled everything and reinstalled again but this time I made sure to right-click on each executable and select "Run as administrator". That seems to have done the trick as my existing WP7 projects are compiling and running successfully and I can create new ones too. I did run into two error messages however -

1. "Zune software is not launched. Retry after making sure that Zune software is launched". I got around this initially by setting the target to Windows Phone 7 Emulator instead of Windows Phone 7 Device in the target dropdown on the main toolbar.
2. "Error: Connection failed because of invalid command-line arguments." I got around this by rebooting as mentioned [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/windowsphone7series/thread/688aac25-7481-415c-89a4-9cca8e6a657b).

Answer (score 1):

Try opening a visual studio command prompt and typing:

devenv /ResetSkipPkgs

Comment: Unfortunately that hasn't helped. VS2010 loaded a bit faster but I still get the "The project type is not supported by this installation error".